# Remove User from Multiple User field JavaScript SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, javascript, sharepoint-addin, rest

I have a SharePoint Hosted Add-In where I've come so far as to Post a user into a "Multiple Users and Groups" field by the users ID and it works great.

The problem I have is that when I try to remove one user from this field I'm not able to find the right solution.

I have tried using REST with no luck:

```
Ajax.Delete("../_api/web/lists/getbytitle('List')/Items(3)/$links/Multiple_Users_Field(9)").done(done).fail(DoError.Ajax)
Ajax.Delete("../_vti_bin/listdata.svc/List(3)/$links/Multiple_Users_Field(9)").done(done).fail(DoError.Ajax)
Ajax.Delete("../_api/web/lists/List(3)/$links/Multiple_Users_Field(9)").done(done).fail(DoError.Ajax)
```

Errors thrown are as follows:

> "Cannot find resource for the request $links."
>   "Resource not found for the segment 'Multiple_Users_Field'."
>   "Cannot find resource for the request List."

Anyone have any suggestions to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out myself!

It was a simple Patch that was needed, this works but it feels like it's unnecessary to loop through the entire collection of people every time one user wants to interact with the field...

```
Ajax.Get("../_api/web/lists/getbytitle('List')/items(" + thisList.ID + ")?$select=Multiple_Users_Field/Id&$expand=Multiple_Users_Field").then(function (data) {

    var idArray = [], users = data.d.Multiple_Users_Field.results;
    for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) { idArray.push(users[i].Id); }

    if ($.inArray(currentUserID, idArray) !== -1) idArray.splice(idArray.indexOf(currentUserID), 1);
    else idArray.push(currentUserID);

    Ajax.Update(thisList.URI, {
        __metadata: { 'type': 'SP.Data.ListListItem' },
        "Multiple_Users_FieldId": { 'results': idArray }
    }).fail(DoError.Ajax);

}, DoError.Ajax);
```

Answer (score 0):

you refer below script for removing one user

```
function Delete()
{ 
jQuery.ajax({url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl+"/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/List(3)/$links/Multiple_Users_Field(9)",
type: "POST",
headers: {
"ACCEPT": "application/json;odata=verbose",
"content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
"X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),   
"X-HTTP-Method": "DELETE"
},
success: function (data) {                     
alert("Deleted Successfuly.");
},
error: function (error) {
alert('n')
}
});
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work, still getting this error:
"Resource not found for the segment 'Multiple_Users_Field'"

Comment: Can you just check by trying with field name as "Multiple_Users_FieldId" in place of "Multiple_Users_Field"

Comment: Still the same error :/ "Resource not found for the segment 'Multiple_Users_FieldId'"

Comment: I tested the above code block work fine for me, can you please check with the internal name for 'Multiple_Users_Field' (without using Id) and try again. hope it works.

Comment: The internal name is correct, could it be because this is a field added in visual studio for a custom list in a SharePoint Hosted App?

Comment: not sure of it friend.